# Win10 wake ups at 2:50 am

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, hibernate

The last few days desktop PC with Windows 10 always wake ups from hibernation at 2:50 am, wake source in Event Viewer is "Unknown".

Updates are configured (in gpedit) to only notify

[image]

"Automatic maintenance" is set to 13:00 and not allowed to wake up.

Wake timers in Power Options disabled.

[image]

In Task Scheduler I do not see any task scheduled for this time + they do not have the wake option enabled.

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what causes this issue. It is Acronis True Image 2016.

Looks like it is a bug because I disabled waking up in backup options but it still wakes my PC to make scheduled backup (it is set to backup every 6 hours). And Acronis wake timer remains even if I disable wake timers in Windows Power Options (as I checked with `powercfg -waketimers` command)

```
>powercfg -waketimers
Timer set by [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume6\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\Schedule2\schedul2.exe
 (AcrSch2Svc) expires at 20:50:00 on 09.11.2015
```

*(why do I even continue to use this buggy piece of garbage after 2012-2014 versions?)*

Comment: so what did you do to prevent this (other than uninstalling the app)? Thanks

Comment: @MattWolf Somehow it fixed itself after several attempts to disable/enable schedule for this backup task.

Comment: thanks for your prompt answer. I am experiencing the same problem but seems unless Ikill the Schedul2 service the waketimer keeps on popping up.